# Libpq framework for swift iOS to work with postgreSQL

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, postgresql

I've been trying to connect my postgreSQL database to an iOS app on swift for quite a while now. I managed to connect it for macOS development by creating Obj-C Bridging header for system provided libpq framework, but macOS development is unusual for me and I want this project to be done well. I found a [libpq framework](https://github.com/spacialdb/libpq.framework) for iOS Obj-C, tried to access it through Bridging Header, but server is not responding to my queries.

I put this within my bridging header

```
#import <libpq/libpq-fe.h>
```

And this is my view controller code

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let conn = PQconnectdb("postgresql://localhost/investProject".cString(using: .utf8))
    if PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_OK {
        let result = PQexec(conn, "SELECT version()")
        for i in 0 ..< PQntuples(result) {
            guard let value = PQgetvalue(result, i, 0) else { continue }
            let dbname = String(cString: value)
            print(dbname)
        }
        PQclear(result)
    }
    PQfinish(conn)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Compiler recognizes all the methods, output is supposed to be the version of my db, but it's empty instead.

Comment: Is the database connection actually successful? Is the query execution successful? In both cases, if not, what's the error?

Comment: When I run the same query in cocoa app, it returns the version of my db, select queries work just fine, but in iOS app it just doesn't return anything. Connection cannot be established, I guess

Comment: Don't guess. Use the debugger or add more logs to determine what happens.

Comment: This is the error I have right now
/Users/artemmisesin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSTest-bxpikdotbomkmjcihkarfqpkwrym/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSTest.app/Frameworks/libpq.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1